# Selecting a row in table view with image and label gives only label text when get selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made this program so i can select two things `image` and a `label` from a table view and get printed in console. when i run this program table view appears and cell contains `image` and `label` but when i select the specific cell, only text is selected and image disappears. while when i run the program it continuously gives memory warnings as well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let   selectedDataG = countryL[indexPath.row]

        countryButton.setTitle(selectedDataG, for: .normal)


        self.countryTable.isHidden = true
        self.flag = 1

        let indexPath = countryT.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = countryT.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! FlagTableViewCell

        let finalresult = currentCell.countryLabel.text!
        let finalFlag = currentCell.flagImage.image!


        print("\(finalFlag)" + "\(finalresult)")

    }


}
```

Comment: will you please share you image size in mb or kb?

Comment: 1kb is the size of images

Comment: Why you have hide countryTable ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a quirk of UITableViewCell, you can use:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

To prevent this happening and stop the grey highlight when the cell is selected, you can then put your custom selection code within `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {}`

As for your memory warning that is something probably unrelated to this and should be looked into.

Comment: Thanx sir, would you try a small example?

Comment: how should i move ahead with `setSelected`

Comment: `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      
      // Configure the view for the selected state
      
      if selected {
         backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      } else {
         backgroundColor = UIColor.white
      }
   }`